# Gaps and Islands query / reset row count based on column seqeunce

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I know there are many examples of this, but still can't find the exact solution.

I am looking to reset a row count based on sequences of 1s and 0s.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (category INT, ts INT,window int)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (category,ts,window)
VALUES  (1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,0),(1,4,0),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(1,7,1),(2,1,0),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1),(2,5,0),(2,6,0),(2,7,1),(2,8,1),(2,9,1),(2,10,1),(2,11,1)
```

[image]

In the table above, I want a row number column that increments by 1, partitioned by category, but the count needs to reset each time the window changes.

Best I've got so far is:

```
SELECT
    x.category,
    ts,
    window, 
    is_group, 
    SUM( is_group ) OVER (PARTITION BY x.category ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING ) * is_group
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE WHEN LAG(window) OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY ts  ) = window THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_group
    FROM @TestTable 
    ) x
ORDER BY x.category,ts
```

This **nearly** works, but for the last stretch it won't increment the row number further than 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (category INT, ts INT,window int)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (category,ts,window)
VALUES  (1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,0),(1,4,0),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(1,7,1),(2,1,0),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1),(2,5,0),(2,6,0),(2,7,1),(2,8,1),(2,9,1),(2,10,1),(2,11,1);


with ctex
as
(
SELECT
x.category,
ts,
window, 
is_group,
sum(is_group) over (partition by category order by ts) as groupstot


FROM
(
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN LAG(window) OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY ts  ) = window THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  is_group
FROM @TestTable 
) x

)
Select * , row_number() over(partition by category,groupstot order by ts) from ctex
ORDER BY category,ts
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it.  Thanks